# Product password protector (woocommerce) modification

Tags: javascript, php, woocommerce

Firstly, please write if anyone will be able to help me here if you need access to the FTP.

I bought the module to WooCommerce:
https://codecanyon.net/item/product-password-protector-woocommerce/7481489
I, for a product to decide the individual code in a panel WooCommerce.

This page is my product of the enabled module:
http://kora.luksusowe-firany.pl/produkt/car-tomato/

How to make to the default button "DODAJ DO KOSZYKA" (Add to Cart) was invisible, and when the user enters the correct password, it will appear?

My guess is that you have to use JS or jQuery.

Is anyone able to help me?

Comment: Hey, if my answer was helpful, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

There's no reliable way to do this client-side, because you'll always have unlocking code in the page code. You'll have to use some server-side programming.